# Avoid empty cells to appear in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a matrix below which is based on the `G/L Account` and `Product` when I merge the net revenue with its percentage value using

```
Base | G/L Weekly Revenue and Its PCT = 
FORMAT( 'Calculations'[Weekly Sales], "Standard" ) & " ( " &  
FORMAT([Revenue | G/L PCT], "0.00%") & " )"
```

[image: enter code here]

It Creates empty cells
[image]

How to avoid this ? many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an IF statement.

```
Base | G/L Weekly Revenue and Its PCT = 
  IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK('Calculations'[Weekly Sales])) && NOT(ISBLANK([Revenue | G/L PCT])) ,
    FORMAT( 'Calculations'[Weekly Sales], "Standard" ) & " ( " &  FORMAT([Revenue | G/L PCT], "0.00%") & " )"
 
  )
```